# ipad-uiview-popup-secondview

Tags: ipad

i want to make popup like this

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1898217/la-foto.jpg

Means... In Backend My Ipad Form has Primary Detail Of Books
IN UITableView,,

When I Select Row Then DetailPage Which Is PopUp Like Above Link,,

How I Can .. ?

I AM TRYing This Code

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Here UIPopoverController Is Use

    self.popOverControl = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithNibName:"DetailPage" bundle:nil];

    self.popOverControl.view.frame =   CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:self.popOverControl.view]; // view is the transparent background
    [self.popOverControl viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the image you provided, It does not seem to be UIPopoverController. It is just UIViewController added in the center of the screen by setting appropriate height, width and x,y position.

> - [self.view addSubView:yourPopOverController.view]